# How can I access my downloads folder using Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, dockerfile

I have to following Dockerfile to create a container image. This works fine for some scripts.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY . /work

WORKDIR /work


RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, I have a script which requires access to my local downloads folder. My understanding is that the container creates an image with the copy of the directory that the Dockerfile sits within. However, I do not understand how to give the container access to my downloads folder outside of this. Any help would be great!

Comment: Why don't you just copy the file from your Downloads folder to your Dockerfile directory? I guess you could also create a symbolic link to the Downloads directory and the Dockerfile will find it.

Comment: In Docker jargon, you need to mount your local download directory from your host machine as a Docker volume. This can be done at runtime with the -v argument. Ex: docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80 nginx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Will take a look at this. In addition, would creating a symbolic link to "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Shared drives" also work?

Comment: Map volumes from container inside to outside system dir

Answer (score 0):

For mounting or sharing purpose you can use docker volume a storing mechanism for docker. You should mount files from your host to the container.

```
docker run -v [host directory path]:[container directory path] -it [image name]
```

This command will just mount your host directory whichever you give access to container

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your downloads folder to your Docker service 
Assuming you have built your service with image name NAMEOFBUILTDOCKER

```sh
docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=pathto/downloads,target=/work \
  NAMEOFYOURBUILTDOCKER
```

Mount is more verbose than —volume but accomplish the same. This will spin up your service in a detached mode(-d), with name devtest where the contents of downloads are in work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can take:

- Give it as a volume (Recommended)
- Change the build context (Just for understanding it better)

**Add a Volume:**

After you build your Dockerfile. You can run it with a volume. Think volume as a shared folder between your host and the container. You can look at documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems).

```
docker run [OPTIONS] -v /path/to/downloads:/work
```

It will build fast and run fast. But if your folder change your container change too. If you want to persist your container;

**Change Build Context:**

When you building your image you are giving it a context.

```
docker build -t my-tag .
```

The dot at the end of the command represents current directory that you run the command. If you want to give your `/Downloads` folder to the context, you need to run build function like below. After that you can state `COPY Downloads/ Downloads/` in your Dockerfile. Remember all of the paths that are use the local file system in Dockerfile is relative to build context. For below example if you want to perform `COPY . /work` line in your answer, you need to change it to `COPY /path/to/your/docker/file/ /work`

```sh
# Go to your users root directory.
cd ~/

# This will add all of the folders including Downloads to your build context. 
docker run build -t my-tag -f /path/to/your/docker/file/Dockerfile .
```

Remember it is recommended to keep your build context small as possible. When you add your all folders to the build context it will be slow. As i said it is for experiment. But if you really want a fast and persistent solution, simply copy your /Download folder in same folder with your Dockerfile. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using docker-compose

> docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: . # DOT (".") means in this root directory, have a dockerfile to build the image
    image: myDownloadAppBuild:latest
    container_name: myDownloadApp
    volumes:
      - <HOST-MACHINE-DIR-PATH>:/app # HOST_MACHINE-DIR-PATH E:/MyDownload AND /app path inside container which points to your download folder. 
    ports:
      - <HOST-PORT-ID>:<CONTAINER-PORT-ID>
```

> dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . /work
WORKDIR /work
VOLUME /app #YOUR DOWNLOAD DIR PATH
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

OR You already have an imperative command to do this

```
docker run <OTHER OPTIONS> -v /path/to/downloads:E:/myAppDownloadMount
```